# Error on a makefile

Tags: java, makefile

I am creating a makefile for compile all the code and run the application. The project in written on JAVA. This is the error that is throw when you execute make:

```
classes
make: classes: Command not found
make: *** [default] Error 127
```

and this is the makefile

```
JFLAGS = -g
JC = javac
JVM = java

.SUFFIXES:
    .java .class

.java.class:
    $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java

CLASSES := $(wildcard src/com/github/jotask/groupproject/*.java)
CLASSES += $(wildcard src/com/github/jotask/groupproject/util/*.java)
CLASSES += $(wildcard src/com/github/jotask/groupproject/model/*.java)
CLASSES += $(wildcard src/com/github/jotask/groupproject/gui/*.java)
CLASSES += $(wildcard src/com/github/jotask/groupproject/connection/*.java)
CLASSES += $(wildcard src/com/github/jotask/groupproject/connection/dao/*.java)

MAIN=Application

default:
    classes

classes:
    $(CLASSES:.java=.class)

run:    $(MAIN).class
    $(JVM) $(MAIN)

clean:
    $(RM) *.class
```

Any idea why this error is throw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here.

```
default:
    classes
```

This says that the target `default` has a recipe with one command in it. That command is `classes`. So when make tries to build the `default` target it tries to run the command `classes` and you get that error.

You meant `default: classes` to have `classes` be a prerequisite of the `default` target.

That said you don't need the `default` target at all and can just get rid of it.

The default target in a makefile is the first explicit target found.

Similarly

```
classes:
    $(CLASSES:.java=.class)
```

is incorrect and should be `classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)` assuming you meant `make classes` to build the `.class` files and

```
.SUFFIXES:
    .java .class
```

is incorrect in the same way and wants to be `.SUFFIXES: .java .class`.

Then you probably also want to add the other classes to the prerequisite list of `run` so that they get (re)built if necessary.

So you probably want something like this all told.

```
JFLAGS = -g
JC = javac
JVM = java

%.class: %.java
    $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $<

SRCS := $(wildcard src/com/github/jotask/groupproject/*.java)
SRCS += $(wildcard src/com/github/jotask/groupproject/util/*.java)
SRCS += $(wildcard src/com/github/jotask/groupproject/model/*.java)
SRCS += $(wildcard src/com/github/jotask/groupproject/gui/*.java)
SRCS += $(wildcard src/com/github/jotask/groupproject/connection/*.java)
SRCS += $(wildcard src/com/github/jotask/groupproject/connection/dao/*.java)

CLASSES := $(SRCS:.java=.class)

MAIN=Application

.PHONY: run
run: $(CLASSES)
    $(JVM) $(MAIN)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) $(CLASSES)

.PHONY: classes
classes: $(CLASSES)
```

Which

- uses more modern [Pattern Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules) (instead of the older [Suffix Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Suffix-Rules))
- names your variables slightly more clearly
- marks the [Phony Targets](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets) correctly
- drops the unnecessary `default` target
- and makes `run` the new default (and makes it build all the classes correctly, automatically)

Comment: Thanks for the answers. That is because I have been following old tutorials I think. This is my first time making a make file. Now I'm getting the following error: http://pastebin.com/HeX7AgHC . I think they can't find that class, and I have been looking inside that package (folder) and is there that file

Comment: What does your makefile look like at this point because it clearly isn't the one I wrote (not exactly). Did you add newlines after `.PHONY:`? Do these classes need to be compiled in a specific order? Do you need specify a `-classpath` to make it find the classes?

Comment: This is the makefile http://pastebin.com/Ndsm2x4H. I didn't add anything. I don't think they need have a specified order (and I don't know if that is true). Maybe the problem is that I am using external libraries? The libraries are on the lib folder in the same level as src folder, that's matter?

Comment: Yes, you did change it. You added newlines after `.PHONY:` multiple times. Don't do that; it is wrong. Are `com.github.jotask.groupproject.gui` and `com.github.jotask.groupproject.gui.Login` not part of your sources? Do those not need to be compiled before `Application.java` that uses them? (Maybe not I don't do java.)

Comment: I thought that new lines doesn't matters, sorry. I just deleted all changes. Yes, gui package holds all the source code for the GUI and gui.Login is a dialog, so yes they are part of the sources. Application.java create a Login dialog. I tried to compile class by class for see classes that needs other classes, and the problem still. For example firstly I compile the Util.java and compiles and later if I compile Util.java and Task.java (that uses Util.java) throw an error that util does not exist

Comment: Where is `Util.class` when it gets built? It sounds like you need to set `-classpath` but I don't know what that needs to be set to or how that works as I don't do Java. Presumably you (or someone else who deals with Java) can know if that is necessary.

Comment: Gets build where the Util.java is. So when it builds all the class files needs to be in the same directory? Maybe that is the problem. I completely lost now. I don't know anything about makefiles or classpat for compile

Comment: This has nothing to do with makefiles. This is *entirely* a java build issue. `-classpath` is an argument to `javac` to tell it where to find class files.